# Spring Boot JUnit 5 Integration Tests with Testcontainers Failing to Launch

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, testcontainers-junit5

I am encountering an issue with running integration tests in a Spring Boot application using JUnit 5 and Testcontainers. Despite following the configuration guidelines, my tests fail to start due to a bean creation exception related to the database connection.

**Dependencies:**
I'm using Testcontainers version 1.19.3 with the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <testcontainers.version>1.19.3</testcontainers.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**application.yml Configuration:**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:10.4://localhost:5432/test-tc
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
```

**Test Class:
**

```
package com.worldline.ancv.messagebroker.web.rest;

import com.worldline.ancv.messagebroker.MessageBrokerApp;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest(classes = MessageBrokerApp.class)
public class TestOff {
    @Test
    public void getAllLogs() {
        // Test implementation
    }
}
```

**Erreur: **

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine DatabaseDriver
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-9) has been closed.
```

Comment: You also need the postgresql driver.

Comment: I already have the driver:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Judging from the error you don't or at least not in the right scope.